# An historical mathematical result-paradox

Tags: ho.history-overview

If you feel like this, please post an information about a mathematical result that satisfies the following conditions to its best:

- the result's authorship is well documented and free of controversy (about the authorship);
- the result is fundamental and its formulation is rather elementary;
- the result is commonly used all the time, it's virtually taken for granted;
- a complete proof of the result is absent in all or almost all monographs;
- very few people know the name of the author of the result.

I have only one such example. Do you know more (of?) such results?

---

**Example** Emil Leon Post's theorem about the elementary logic (without quantifiers) that states that tautologies and theorems are the same.

PS. I have no doubt that Emil Leon Post was the greatest logician ever. In addition to the result mentioned above, he formalized mathematics independently of David Hilbert, and in about the same time. Post proved the independence result years before Kurt Godel. He developed apparatus equivalent to Turing machines about the same time as Turing. Etc.

PPS. The above-mentioned Post theorem is not as easy as many people would think (if they stopped to do so). The illusion comes from the fact that finite Boolean algebra is about as simple as possible. However, a minor modification of Boolean axioms can be very hard to show that it leads or does not lead to actual Boolean Algebra. This must be the reason why complete proofs of the Post Theorem are so hard to encounter in the literature.

Comment: What is that sick obsessive downvoting, a post after a post? This whole voting was always wrong, anti-mathematical but these days it's extreme, super-ugly. It's time to get rid of all this nonsensical voting that does a lot of harm by pushing us away form mathematics, be it OPs or potential readers. All this is very prone to abuse!

Comment: "sick obsessive". Well, there is currently just one downvote, not so obsessive after all. Anyways, maybe you should write explicitly the example you have, instead of keeping it secret, in order to make clear what kind of answers you expect.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi, sure, I can extend my Q. by the example. I thought that it'd be more interesting if others would start.

Comment: It seems a typical situation when a result is believed true by everybody, and the proof is actually spread in various papers the literature even if not so clearly. As a result, writing a proof with all details can be a thankless task, because one has to solve  all the unexpected technical difficulties  *and* to convince everybody that the difficulties were not trivial. They will say: "we already knew it!"

Comment: @PietroMajer, it's truly interesting what you've written. However, this is still different from the situation that I've described in my Q. And I hope that the example that I have provided will convince you (?).